# How do you find range of array variables starting from the first occurrence to the last?

Tags: php

**The problem:**

A person gets paid starting from their first appointment for the day until their last appointment of the day - non-booked time in-between included.

**Example Array looks like this:**

```
array(
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => 2014-12-08 09:00:00 )
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => 2014-12-08 10:30:00 )
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
)
```

**Desired output:**

```
array(
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => 2014-12-08 09:00:00 )
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => )
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [booking] => 2014-12-08 10:30:00 )
)
```

Count = 4

How can I extract the desired data-set?

Comment: I need to produce a "timesheet" which is essentially a list from the first to last appointment.  I have been able to step through and discard the first 2 appointments... and as I type this I could probably just step through the array backwards and discard those couldnt I? lol *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prematurely asked the question I think and there may be a more efficient way to do this but running the array through the two loops below removed the leading and training blank entries to their respective first occurences:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($timesheet); $i++){
    if ($timesheet[$i]['booking'] == 0) {
        unset($timesheet[$i]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

$timesheet = array_values($timesheet);

for($i=count($timesheet)-1; $i > 0; $i--){
    if ($timesheet[$i]['booking'] == 0) {
        unset($timesheet[$i]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```